# Show bitmap size in Textview

Tags: android, bitmap, size, textview

I have this problem.I am using decodeByteArray to decode and decrypted data as an image and after that I am trying to get the actual size (in bytes , not width & height) of that image and show it in textview.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedData , 0, decryptedData .length);    //decoding bytearrayoutputstream to bitmap
int i = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight() ;

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
txt.setText(i);
```

The code is running without any errors,but the size is not showing up in the TextView.Any suggestions?

Comment: if you log `i` what do you get?

Comment: When I do this : Log.i("Size","Bitmap size "+ i);  I don't get anything in the LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this instead and tell me the result

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedData , 0, decryptedData .length); 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
txt.setText(String.valueOf(stream.size()));
```

Comment: One question, what is bmp?My bitmap image or some other variable?

Comment: are you getting zero? Add Log.v("",decryptedData.length) check it.

Comment: The log's are not showing up in the LogCat, I don't know why, including the two Log's that I have in my code.

Comment: well if logcat is not working ,,, you should close the avd and eclipse and restart.. if it is not showing but working ! then there is a problem in the execution flow! start a chat with me (i dont know how)

Comment: @psychenaut let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1867/discussion-between-sherif-and-psychenaut)

Answer (score 1):

`TextView.setText(int resId)` is not supposed to be used like that. The `i` should be a resource id like `R.string.my_string_here`.

What you actually want is

```
txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
  BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
  int width = bounds.outWidth;
  int height = bounds.outHeight;
```

Comment: I actually need the bytes size of the bitmap,sorry I forget to mention that in question. I will update that.

Answer (score 0):

At this line :

```
int i = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight() ;
```

you should use getWidth() not GetRowBytes(), because getRowBytes() returns the number of bytes between rows in the bitmap's pixels, and getWidth() returns the width of the image.

Comment: Actually I need the size of an image in bytes as I edit the question a few minutes ago.Sorry about the misunderstanding.